# rplay error while loading shared libWFC.so

Tags: pi-3b+, streaming

I wanted to install rplay on my Raspberry Pi 3b+.
I followed an instruction from the web and everything worked fine until I wanted to start the actual program.

I am not able to access the webinterface, not even via localhost (connected via vnc).

If I try to start rplay, it says:

"rplay: error while loading shared libraries: libWFC.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I do not know which directory is missing, so I hope for ideas!

Comment: Please tell us what steps you followed to install `rplay`. When you say, "I followed an instruction from the web", only you know what that instruction was. We can't help you if we don't know what you did.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (debian stretch + rpi3b+) this has fixed an issue:

```
rpi-update
sudo apt install libjpeg8
```

The problem maybe is that some of the libraries are renamed in Stretch, I think.
You could also try to do the following manually if the libraries are still missing:

```
cd /opt/vc/lib
sudo ln -s libbrcmEGL.so libEGL.so
sudo ln -s libbrcmGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so
sudo ln -s libbrcmOpenVG.so libOpenVG.so
sudo ln -s libbrcmWFC.so libWFC.so
```

Comment: this fixed the issue in both my raspberrys. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Deinstall `rplay` you have followed by an instruction from the web.

Then execute this commands:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install rplay-client
```

Reboot and then *rplay* should find all libraries it needs.

**Update:**
As stated by comments from *@FD_* there is another program named `rplay` and belongs to the **AirPlay server**. So maybe my answer does not cover the issue of the question?

Comment: For all fellow readers: These instructions install a different software that is also called rplay. The question was about the AirPlay server called rplay, while this answer is about a Unix network audio streaming software called rPlay.

Comment: @FD_ OK, but where do you can see it from the question?

Comment: 1. I had the very same problem as the OP (with the rplay AirPlay server) 
2. There are tons of instructions on the web for setting up an AirPlay mirroring server with rplay 
3. Only the rplay AirPlay server has a webinterface (AFAICT) 
4. libWFC seems to be related to OpenGL, which wouldn't make sense for an audio-only program like the rplay audio streaming software.

That being said, I absolutely agree that the question was ambiguous. I just failed to set up AirPlay rplay with your instructions, until I realized it was about a different program, so I thought I'd leave a note here.

Comment: @FD_ I think it's an important information for other users turning in this. I suggest you make your comments an answer. I will upvote it.

Comment: I don't think that information is enough for an answer on its own. It doesn't answer the OP's question. Maybe you can just add a line to your answer telling it is about the rplay audio streaming program?